# How to add shared preferences in phonegap?

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build

I am not able to find out a way to add shared preferences to my app,

Anybody can please give me a tutorial link how to do it in windows environment.

And how to add service to phonegap?

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure what you mean by shared preferences. Do you mean how to store user preferences for different users? If so, you would need to store each preference in the device database and pull them out for what ever user is using the app. Take a look at [this](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.9.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Database) for how to interface with the DB.

What do you mean by "how to do it in a windows environment"? If you mean how to do it for Windows device apps, it doesnt matter. Doing it for Windows is the same code as doing it for iOS and Android. But if you mean how to develop the code in a windows environment, that doesnt matter either. Since you used the tag "phonegap-build" I am assuming you are using PhoneGap Build and not straight Cordova. With PhoneGap Build you can develop your HTML/CSS/JS on any device, Zip it and upload it to build.phonegap.com and it will build the app for you and it doesnt matter what OS the code was written on.

How to add a service to phonegap? Well technically you dont. You build a service for you app using JavaScript not for phonegap. Personally, I prefer to use jQuery and json. Take a look at this [example/documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) of accessing a json web-service with jQuery.

In the future, you should post here about things you have tried and what the result was. Typically, people will not help unless you show that you have tried to help yourself first. You caught me on a good morning :)

Answer (score -1):

This is code example for you, and you can check more [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html)

```
    //Create/Open a SharedPreferences(file xml) with name: "filename" and mode:MODE_PRIVATE(only your app read/write) 
    SharedPreferences shared = getSharedPreferences("filename", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    //Create editor to set String or anything into SharedPreferences file
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = shared.edit();
    //Set Content for SharedPreferences file 
    editor.putString("user","content set for key 'user' ");
    editor.putString("pass","content set for key 'pass' ");
    //Important. Commit after set value. Same commit transaction in SQL 
    editor.commit();
    //Get content from SharedPreferences file
    String username = shared.getString("user", "defaul_value if key user not available");
    String password = shared.getString("pass", "defaul_value if key user not available");
```

And service in android. More detail [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html)

Comment: He doesn't need SharedPrefence in Native Android, we want to do that in phonegap (JS, I think). Any Idea ?